# AutoComplete não funciona em adicionar remover inputs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, autocompletar

Estou desenvolvendo um formulário de orçamentos e nele eu adiciono e removo linhas para cadastrar produtos e em cada  linhas tem dois campos de autocomplete, onde busca o produto por código ou por nome. A primeira linha sempre é fixa para começar o preenchimento e nela o autocomplete funciona, já as demais que são adicionadas quantas vezes o usuário quiser não está funcionando o autocomplete. Elas não 'capturam o evento do autocomplete', parece que não  "enxerga no DOM".

**Código de adição e remoção das linhas**

```
  (function($) {

  RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');

    tr.fadeOut(400, function(){ 
      tr.remove(); 
    }); 

    return false;
  };

  AddTableRow = function() {

      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";

      cols += '<td width="13%"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-search"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_code_product[]" id="form_code_product" placeholder="0002"> </div></div></td>';
      cols += '<td width="30%"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-search"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_name_product[]" id="form_name_product" placeholder="Mesa"> </div></div> </td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_price_product" id="form_price_product"> </td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_quantity_product" id="form_quantity_product"> </td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_total_product" id="form_total_product"> </td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_obs_product"> </td>';

      cols += '<td class="actions">';
      cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>';
      cols += '</td>';

      newRow.append(cols);

      $("#products-table").append(newRow);

      return false;
  };

})(jQuery);
```

**Código do autocomplete**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_code_product, #form_name_product").autocomplete({

        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false,
        appentTo: '#form_register_budget',

        source: function(request, response){

          $.ajax({
            url: "filter/product_code",
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            data:{'term' : request.term }
          }).done(function( products ){

              if( products.length > 0 ){

                 products = products.split( ',' );

                 response( $.each( products, function( key, item ){
                    return({
                        label: item  
                    });

                 }));
              }
          });
        }
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro principal no seu código é que está repetindo `id`s ao adicionar novas linhas na tabela. Desta forma o Autocomplete só iria pegar o primeiro `id` que encontrar, ignorado o restante. Isso porque um `id` deve ser único na página, ou seja, não pode haver mais de um `id` na página com o mesmo nome.

Além do que, como você disse, ao adicionar novos elementos no DOM, o Autocomplete precisa ser reiniciado para incluir esses novos elementos.

Faça o seguinte:

Antes de mais nada, troque todos os `id`s por `class` no JavaScript e no HTML:

```
$(".form_code_product, .form_name_product").autocomplete(...
```

No caso do HTML, é só incluir o nome do que era `id` dentro da lista de classes do elemento:

```
                                                       ↓
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm form_code_product" name="form_code_product[]"
```

Alterado os `id`s para `class`, no script, coloque todo o código dentro do mesmo escopo. Em vez de fazer como está fazendo, assim, criando dois escopos:

```
(function($) {
  // código
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  // código
});
```

Coloque tudo no mesmo escopo, dentro de:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // todo o código
});
```

Agora crie um objeto com as opções do Autocomplete:

```
var ac_opts = {
     width: 260,
     matchContains: true,
     selectFirst: false,
     appentTo: '#form_register_budget',

     source: function(request, response){

       $.ajax({
         url: "filter/product_code",
         type: 'get',
         dataType: 'html',
         data:{'term' : request.term }
       }).done(function( products ){

           if( products.length > 0 ){

              products = products.split( ',' );

              response( $.each( products, function( key, item ){
                 return({
                     label: item  
                 });

              }));
           }
       });
     }
}
```

Crie uma função onde será iniciado o Aucomplete:

```
function ativaAC(){
    $(".form_code_product, .form_name_product").autocomplete(ac_opts);
}
```

Na função onde são adicionadas linhas, chame a função `ativaAC()` para reiniciar o Autocomplete:

```
AddTableRow = function() {

   var newRow = $("<tr>");
   var cols = "";

   cols += '<td width="13%"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-search"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm form_code_product" name="form_code_product[]" placeholder="0002"> </div></div></td>';
   cols += '<td width="30%"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-search"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm form_name_product" name="form_name_product[]" placeholder="Mesa"> </div></div> </td>';
   cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_price_product" classs="form_price_product"> </td>';
   cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_quantity_product" class="form_quantity_product"> </td>';
   cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_total_product" class="form_total_product"> </td>';
   cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_obs_product"> </td>';

   cols += '<td class="actions">';
   cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>';
   cols += '</td>';

   newRow.append(cols);

   $("#products-table").append(newRow);

   ativaAC();

   return false;
};
```

Feito tudo isso, seu código irá funcionar normalmente.

**Veja o código completo e corrigido:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  RemoveTableRow = function(handler) {
    var tr = $(handler).closest('tr');

    tr.fadeOut(400, function(){ 
      tr.remove(); 
    }); 

    return false;
  };

  AddTableRow = function() {

      var newRow = $("<tr>");
      var cols = "";

      cols += '<td width="13%"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-search"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm form_code_product" name="form_code_product[]" placeholder="0002"> </div></div></td>';
      cols += '<td width="30%"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-search"></i></div><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm form_name_product" name="form_name_product[]" placeholder="Mesa"> </div></div> </td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm form_price_product" name="form_price_product"> </td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm form_quantity_product" name="form_quantity_product"> </td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm form_total_product" name="form_total_product"> </td>';
      cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="form_obs_product"> </td>';

      cols += '<td class="actions">';
      cols += '<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>';
      cols += '</td>';

      newRow.append(cols);

      $("#products-table").append(newRow);

      ativaAC();

      return false;
  };

   var ac_opts = {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false,
        appentTo: '#form_register_budget',

        source: function(request, response){

          $.ajax({
            url: "filter/product_code",
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            data:{'term' : request.term }
          }).done(function( products ){

              if( products.length > 0 ){

                 products = products.split( ',' );

                 response( $.each( products, function( key, item ){
                    return({
                        label: item  
                    });

                 }));
              }
          });
        }
   }

   function ativaAC(){
       $(".form_code_product, .form_name_product").autocomplete(ac_opts);
   }

   ativaAC();

});
```

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente. Realmente tinha me esquecido da questão do ID so poder ser único. E obrigado pela otimização do código também.

Comment: me surgiu um outro problema, porque assim, por exemplo eu digito o codigo e ao clicar nas opções ele preenche alguns campos dessa linha com as informações referentes a ele. Então preciso diferenciar cada class da lista, porque senão ele vai preencher igual todas. Seu eu colocar um contador , incrementando uma class sera que funciona? Exemplo:
var count = 1; 
<class="minha-classe '+count+'">

Mas como também iria referenciar também no código? Preciso também somar os subtotais de cada linha  e dar total geral depois

Comment: ficaria assim: $('table tbody').closest('tr').find('.form_name_product').val( product.product_name );   ?

Comment: Assim não. Ao clicar selecionando a opção do autocomplete, vc deve pegar esse input onde será inserido o valor do autocomplete. Peraí que vou dar uma olhada aqui.

Comment: é porque uso SELECT para que na hora que seja clicado no item ele dispara esse evento:

https://pastebin.com/q2Agb1bi

Comment: Tem que adiconar um evento nas opções do Autocomplete.... vou adicionar na resposta...

Comment: No início do `ac_opts` vc adiciona `select: function(event){
         $(event.target).closest("tr").find(".form_name_product").val("teste");
      },
`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79167/discussion-between-dvd-and-thimoreira).

Comment: te mandei mensagem no chat